# Pass values to XML from database in Android

Tags: android

How do i do an edit form functionality in android. I am a new bee to android. How do i pass on database values to XML and then submit it back

Comment: What XML, in where and what you want to achieve? Pls. be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

These are very generic questions. Maybe you can try working out the Notepad tutorial and learn some edit form / db skills from there?

http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/notepad/index.html

If this doesn't answer your question could you be more specific of what you are trying to achieve (code examples / ui screenshots)?

Cheers,

Johan